# clang compiles this snippet in Coliru, but not in Compiler Explorer. Why?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

```
struct A{
   constexpr A(){}
};

A a;

int main(){}
```

See live examples: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40118404a967e199) and [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/klm2pi).

Comment: Don't forget the compile flags https://godbolt.org/g/pWndZO

Comment: Different compiler options? Like `clang++ -std=c++1z`.

Comment: @krzaq Thanks. What are the default flags when I leave the box empty?

Comment: Not sure about clang but `-std=c++11` is default on in gcc 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the following compile options in coliru, while not in compiler explorer:

```
-std=c++1z -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors -pthread
```

Because your code uses `constexpr`, the important part here is `-std=c++1z` to enable modern C++ support (C++17 to be precise; note that `-std=c++11` to enable C++11 is enough here).

Comment: What are the flags when I leave the box empty in compiler explorer?

Comment: They are the default values of clang, which I don't know. But you proved here that for clang 3.9.0, C++11 support is disabled by default